# I'm getting values outside of the fields on forms - Using Zurb Foundation CSS

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, forms, sass

I'm having issue with some form fields that have their values outside the field box.

Here a screenshot and the code sample.

focus on the second field on `Start Date` and it's value goes to the top of the form.

[image: focus on the second field on <code>Start Dates</code> and it's value goes to the top of the form]

```
<%= form_tag(add_carrer_profile_path, id: "onboarding-school-form", method: :post) do %>

     <%# ... other fields below ... %>

     <div class="row">
            <div class="large-6 column end">
              <label> Start Date *</label>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="large-6 column end">
                  <%= label_tag 'profile_education_start_month' do %>
                      <%= number_field_tag 'profile_education[start_month]', nil, id: 'profile_education_start_month', max: 12, min: 1, class: 'fields_relative', placeholder: 'MM', required: true %>
                  <% end %>
                </div>
                <div class="large-6 column end">
                  <%= label_tag 'profile_education_start_year' do %>
                      <%= number_field_tag 'profile_education[start_year]', nil, id: 'profile_education_start_year', max: 2020, min: 1985, class: 'fields_relative', placeholder: 'YYYY', required: true %>
                  <% end %>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="large-6 column end">
              <label> End Date *</label>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="large-6 column end">
                  <%= label_tag 'profile_education_end_month' do %>
                      <%= number_field_tag 'profile_education[end_month]', nil, id: 'profile_education_end_month', max: 12, min: 1, class: 'fields_relative end_date_field', placeholder: 'MM', required: true %>
                  <% end %>
                </div>
                <div class="large-6 column end">
                  <%= label_tag 'profile_education_end_year' do %>
                      <%= number_field_tag 'profile_education[end_year]', nil, id: 'profile_education_end_year', max: 2020, min: 1985, class: 'fields_relative end_date_field', placeholder: 'YYYY', required: true %>
                  <% end %>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
<% end %>
```

Edit 1:
When I put these `date fields` relative the value goes back inside. But it's aligned to the right. Even if I put `text-align: left` it keeps on the right.

Edit 2:
By inspecting the css on the field, here is how it looks like:

[image: Inspect Element <code>1</code> on the browser]
[image: Inspect Element <code>2</code> on the browser]
[image: Inspect Element <code>3</code> on the browser]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are misusing the end class. Check out the documentation for the Zurb Foundation and specifically go to the section about "Incomplete Rows" to see how this is supposed to be used. I think that your code should look something more like this:

```
 <div class="large-6 column">
                  <label> Start Date *</label>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="large-6 column">
                      <%= label_tag 'profile_education_start_month' do %>
                          <%= number_field_tag 'profile_education[start_month]', nil, id: 'profile_education_start_month', max: 12, min: 1, class: 'fields_relative', placeholder: 'MM', required: true %>
                      <% end %>
                    </div>
                    <div class="large-6 column">
                      <%= label_tag 'profile_education_start_year' do %>
                          <%= number_field_tag 'profile_education[start_year]', nil, id: 'profile_education_start_year', max: 2020, min: 1985, class: 'fields_relative', placeholder: 'YYYY', required: true %>
                      <% end %>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div> 

<div class="large-6 column end">
              <label> End Date *</label>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="large-6 column">
                  <%= label_tag 'profile_education_end_month' do %>
                      <%= number_field_tag 'profile_education[end_month]', nil, id: 'profile_education_end_month', max: 12, min: 1, class: 'fields_relative end_date_field', placeholder: 'MM', required: true %>
                  <% end %>
                </div>
                <div class="large-6 column end">
                  <%= label_tag 'profile_education_end_year' do %>
                      <%= number_field_tag 'profile_education[end_year]', nil, id: 'profile_education_end_year', max: 2020, min: 1985, class: 'fields_relative end_date_field', placeholder: 'YYYY', required: true %>
                  <% end %>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and help @JackMoody. Still having the issue. Btw... When I put these date fields `position: relative;` the value goes back inside, but it's aligned to the right. Even if I put text-align: left; it keeps on the right.

Comment: Any way you could make a jsfiddle or codepen for this? Or have you solved this problem yet?